# How can I set this GUI in the way I want using Guizero?

Tags: python, user-interface, guizero

I'm using Guizero to make a simple GUI in Python, and I want it to look pretty much like this:
[image: This is the GUI I want]

But I'm coding and for some reason I'm getting a blank space which is moving my elements. Also, I'm usign align bottom in my bottom boxes but they don't show unless I make the window grow:
[image: Blank space for no reason]
When I make the window grow the two boxes appear:
[image: :)]

And this is my code:
[image: Simple code]

What am I doing wrong? I didn't really find much documentation on Guizero

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for Guizero is here: https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/, click on the Widgets menu dropdown. I find it pretty good.

Using guizero is simple but not easy. It does what it does but, it is difficult to get it to do what you really want it to do.

I find that one has to constrain objects in guizero, to stop them deciding themselves where they want to be, by putting them in boxes in each functional area of your form. In your case the left and right boxes need to be in a "middle" box between your top and bottom boxes. This gets rid of the extra space.

I also find that I need to add padding to stop objects being too close to edges and to each other, and to force the layout, for example, in grid layout. For padding I use a "Text" widget with empty text, and control its size with the width and height properties which are character sizes for the text widget.

I have made a rough example of what you said that you wanted. Note the middleBox, and the padding "Text" widgets especially around the buttons in the grid. Note also that the option and input text varies position in spite of being left aligned, ah well.

[Form produced by the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYtEY.jpg)

```
    from guizero import App, Text, TitleBox, Box, TextBox, CheckBox, PushButton
    app = App(title="Restaurante")
    app.width = 1280
    topHeight = 100
    middleHeight = 500
    bottomHeight = 100
    app.height = topHeight + middleHeight + bottomHeight
    rightWidth = 380
    leftWidth = 900
    app.width = rightWidth + leftWidth
    paddingHeight = 1

    topBox = Box(app, align="top", width= "fill", height= topHeight, border= True)
    padding01 = Text(topBox, text="", height = paddingHeight)
    message = Text(topBox, text="TOP BOX", align="top", height = 1, size = 18)
    padding02 = Text(topBox, text="", height = paddingHeight)
    #messagel = Text(app, text="DeLeitese con nuestros exquisitos pLatos")

    middleBox = Box(app, align="top", width= "fill", height= middleHeight, border= True)
    leftBox = Box(middleBox, width= leftWidth, height= middleHeight, border= True, align="left", layout="grid")
    inputLabel01 = Text(leftBox, text="Input01", grid=[0,0], width = 20, size = 14, align="left")
    inputText01 = TextBox(leftBox, text="Type Input01 here", width = 40, grid=[1,0])
    inputLabel02 = Text(leftBox, text="Inp02", grid=[0,1], width = 20, size = 14, align="left")
    inputText02 = TextBox(leftBox, text="Type Inp02 here", width = 40, grid=[1,1])
    inputLabel03 = Text(leftBox, text="Input03", grid=[0,2], width = 20, size = 14, align="left")
    inputText03 = TextBox(leftBox, text="Type Input03 here", width = 40, grid=[1,2])

    rightBox = Box(middleBox, width= rightWidth, height=middleHeight, border= True, layout="grid")
    option01 = CheckBox (rightBox, text="", width = 2, grid=[0,0])
    option01Text = Text (rightBox, text="Option01                      ", width = 30, align="left", grid=[1,0])
    paddingOpt01 = Text(topBox, text="", height = paddingHeight)
    option02 = CheckBox (rightBox, text="", width = 2, grid=[0,1])
    option02Text = Text (rightBox, text="Option02 is really gigantic   ", width = 30, align="left", grid=[1,1])
    paddingOpt02 = Text(topBox, text="", height = paddingHeight)
    option03 = CheckBox (rightBox, text="", width = 2, grid=[0,2])
    option03Text = Text (rightBox, text="Option03                      ", width = 30, align="left", grid=[1,2])
    paddingOpt03 = Text(topBox, text="", height = paddingHeight)

    bottomBox = Box(app, align="top", width= "fill", height= bottomHeight, border= True)
    leftBottomBox = Box(bottomBox, align= "left",width= leftWidth, height= bottomHeight, border= True, layout = "grid")
    paddingBot00 = Text(leftBottomBox, text="", width = 20, height = paddingHeight, grid = [0,0])
    paddingBot10 = Text(leftBottomBox, text="", width = 20, height = paddingHeight, grid = [1,0])
    message = Text(leftBottomBox, text="LEFT BOTTOM BOX", grid = [2,0])
    paddingBot01 = Text(leftBottomBox, text="", width = 20, height = paddingHeight, grid = [0,1])
    buttonOK = PushButton(leftBottomBox, text="OK", width = 20, height = 1, grid = [1,1])
    paddingBot21 = Text(leftBottomBox, text="", width = 20, height = paddingHeight, grid = [2,1])
    buttonCancel = PushButton(leftBottomBox, text="Cancel", width = 20, height = 1, grid = [3,1])
    rightBottomBox = Box(bottomBox, align= "right",width= rightWidth, height=bottomHeight, border= True)
    message = Text(rightBottomBox, text="RIGHT BOTTOM BOX")
    app.display()
```